# Disallowing use of a given .net framework library

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, namespaces

I have a program for which I want to provide an abstraction for the file system so that IO operations for reading files, creating directories and so forth are performed always against a given implementation obtained via a given factory.

For example, instead of accessing System.IO.File you'll need to access MyLib.IO.File which contains a given set of operations for file supported by the system and where the actual implementation will be provided by either IOC or a singleton factory.

However, someone unfamiliar with the system might just reference System.IO and start directly working on files in the file system. If his actual configuration instanciates the standard System.IO wrapper all will work fine on his machine but will eventually break when the underlying file system changes.

Is there any way to warn or even better disallow the usage of certain namespaces in a VS application so that the user knows he shouldn't be using that part of the .NET framework but another library provided to get that specific functionality?

Comment: Sounds more like a training issue than a technical problem

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There's a way, it's called clear and short API documentation. Clear enough to encourage reading and short enough to make the developer not interesting in abandon before finish.

I mean enforcing use of your own libraries doesn't sound bad, you have your arguments, but obscure the BCL libraries sounds pretty bad.

Answer (score 1):

CASPOL would be annoying and not many developers read API documentation until they get stuck.

Release a Build Script that interrogates the Solution using Assembly Binding Log Viewer (Fuslogvw.exe) for System.IO and etc unwanted references. You could go further too and use Reflection or even Introspection to see if the use of System.IO is ok or not. IMHO this option feels the least intrusive and provides some guarantee the correct DLLs/Namespaces will be used for a release.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is not.

Edit:

Well, maybe. Use of `System.IO.*` can be restricted using Code Access Security (or whatever its replacement is in .NET 4.x), however this means that you need to control the application entirely (e.g. you loading add-in code, rather than another program merely using your assembly).